# Getting Google Form's response spreadsheet link for forms created with FormApp

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I can make Google Forms inside GAS, like so.

```js
const form = FormApp.create(formTitle);
const formUrl = form.getEditUrl();
```

The created forms will have different contents and URLs depending on the run, and also different spreadsheets that will record the responses.

Is it possible to get the links to those spreadsheets with GAS, or does it have to be done manually each time by clicking the Create Spreadsheet button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms hasn't a spreadsheet by default, you have to set the form responses destination, and in order to do that you have to create the spreadsheet.

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setdestinationtype,-id

Related

- [Google Scripts - Can't Find Destination Sheet After Form Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60803740/1595451)